# Docker Compose and execute command on starting container

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am trying to get my head around the COMMAND option in docker compose. In my current docker-compose.yml i start the prosody docker image (https://github.com/prosody/prosody-docker) and i want to create a list of users when the container is actually started.

The documentation of the container states that a user can be made using environment options `LOCAL, DOMAIN, and PASSWORD`, but this is a single user. I need a list of users.

When reading some stuff around the internet it seemed that using the command option i should be able to execute commands in a starting or running container.

```
xmpp:
    image: prosody/prosody
    command: prosodyctl register testuser localhost testpassword
    ports:
        - "5222:5222"
        - "127.0.0.1:5347:5347"
```

But this seems not to work, i checked to running container using `docker exec -it <imageid> bash` but the user is not created.

Is it possible to execute a command on a started container using docker-compose or are there other options?

Comment: The command option overrides the default command from the docker container so it can't be used for what you want. Maybe you can create a script that first starts your environment using `docker-compose start` and then uses `docker exec <your container id> prosodyctl register ...` to create users in that container?

Answer (score 2):

`CMD` is directly related to `ENTRYPOINT` in Docker (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) question for an explanation). So when changing one of them, you also have to check how this affects the other. If you look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/prosody/prosody-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile), you will see that the default command is to start prosody through `CMD ["prosodyctl", "start"]`. [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/prosody/prosody-docker/blob/master/entrypoint.sh) just passes this command through as Adrian mentioned. However, your command overrides the default command, so your prosody demon is never started. Maybe you want to try something like

```
xmpp:
    image: prosody/prosody
    command: sh -c prosodyctl register testuser localhost testpassword && prosodyctl start
    ports:
        - "5222:5222"
        - "127.0.0.1:5347:5347"
```

instead. More elegant and somehow what the creator seems to have intended (judging from the entrypoint.sh script) would be something like

```
xmpp:
    image: prosody/prosody
    environment:
        - LOCAL=testuser
        - DOMAIN=localhost
        - PASSWORD=testpassword
    ports:
        - "5222:5222"
        - "127.0.0.1:5347:5347"
```

To answer your final question: no, it is not possible (as of now) to execute commands on a running container via docker-compose. However, you can easily do this with docker:

```
docker exec -i prosody_container_name prosodyctl register testuser localhost testpassword
```

where `prosody_container_name` is the name of your running container (use `docker ps` to list running containers).

Answer (score 1):

The `COMMAND` instruction is exactly the same as what is passed at the end of a `docker run` command, for example `echo "hello world"` in:

```
docker run debian echo "hello world"
```

The command is interpreted as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT` of the image, which in debian's case is `/bin/bash`. In the case of your image, it gets passed to [this script](https://github.com/prosody/prosody-docker/blob/master/entrypoint.sh). Looking at that script, your command will just get passed to the shell. I would have expected any command you pass to run successfully, but the container will exit once your command completes. Note that the default command is set in the Dockerfile to `CMD ["prosodyctl", "start"]` which is presumably a long-running process which starts the server.

I'm not sure how Prosody works (or even what it is), but I think you probably want to either map in a config file which holds your users, or set up a data container to persist your configuration. The first solution would mean adding something like:

```
volumes:
  - my_prosodoy_config:/etc/prosody
```

To the docker-compose file, where `my_prosody_config` is a directory holding the config files.

The second solution could involve first creating a data container like:

```
docker run -v /etc/prosody -v /var/log/prosody --name prosody-data prosody-docker echo "Prosody Data Container"
```

(The echo should complete, leaving you with a stopped container which has volumes set up for the config and logs. Just make sure you don't `docker rm` this container by accident!)

Then in the docker-compose file add:

```
volumes_from:
   - prosody-data
```

*Hopefully* you can then add users by running `docker exec` as you did before, then running `prosodyctl register` at the command line. But this is dependent on how prosody and the image behave.